# ASP.NET MVC 4 with EntityFramework layering concern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My question relates to layering in a solution I am currently working on.
I get the feeling that the path I'm on is breaking the layer separation and would like some feedback on that.

My current project is a ASP.NET MVC4 app, that uses autofac, EF 5.0 Code First.

I have the following layers: Domain, Data, Services and Presentation

The data layer uses a repository which returns results from the DB via EntityFramework. This repository returns an IQueryable<> object as the set of retrieved results. (This is because DbSet<> of EF is derived from IQueryable<>).

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    T GetById(object id);
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> Entities { get; }
}
```

The Services layer makes use of the said repository and thus operates on IQueryable<> objects. By default, I've implemented my Service methods to return IEnumerbale<> objects for data retreival, thus my presentation layer should always receive a IEnumerable<> collection from the service.

Hopefully the context is clear enough. This is my problem:

I have the following two domain classes:

```
public class Video
    {
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual VideoCategory VideoCategory { get; set; }
        public int VideoCategoryId { get; set; }
    }
public class VideoCategory
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Video> Videos { get; set; }
        public VideoCategory()
        {
            Videos = new List<Video>();
        }
    }
```

Also, I have the following VideoCategoryModel class defined in my presentation layer, which i need for binding in the ui:

```
public class VideoCategoryModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int VideoCount { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, I would like to get a collection of objects representing video categories with a count of each category's videos. Of course, I want to do this without fetching all the Video objects. In order to accomplish this, the service method returns a IQueryable< VideoCategory > to my presentation such that I can query it like this in my controller:

```
    var convertedResults = from videoCategory in service.GetVideoCategories() 
                            select new VideoCategoryModel()
                            { 
                             Title = videoCategory.Title, 
                             Description = videoCategory.Description, 
                             VideoCount = videoCategory.Videos.Count
                            };
```

This query will be nicely interpreted by EF which will run a nice, fast Select query on the DB, with a count instead of fetching all Video objects.
This is the GetVideoCategories implementation:

```
public IQueryable< VideoCategory > GetVideoCategories()
        {
            return videoCategoryRepository.Entities;
        }
```

I would like to know if I'm breaking my separation of concerns and layering by returning a 
IQueryable< VideoCategory > (actually the EF DbSet) directly to my controller, instead of returning a List<> of objects.

Also, after calling the ToList() method on the IQueryable<> object it will be impossible to get the Count EF so nicely translates into SQL, so again I cannot return a List< VideoCategory > from the service.

So to summarize the question. Is returning the EFDbSet directly to the controller a good idea ? Am I breaking the layer separation ? What are my alternatives if so.

Thank you.

Comment: I've run into a similar issue. The best advice that I know of is to carefully look at the contract that your interface is defining. Is the object returned by a repository always guaranteed to be queryable? Do you do unit testing? If so, it can be very difficult to mock the IQueryable.

Comment: You should start by answering questions: What is the added value of my repository layer? What is the added value of my service layer? Because if the whole point of repository is to wrap DbSet and the whole point of service is to wrap repository they are both completely redundant.

Comment: I agree with mike at the mock objects. I think you should look into communicating with DTO over WCF. here's a good example on DTO usage with WCF http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91835/WCF-by-Example-Chapter-III-Response

Comment: @MikeBantegui I think the object returned by the repository should always be IQueryable since we may change the repository or the data layer with a different DB provider so I think we need something which will not depend on other layers;

Comment: @LadislavMrnka The added value is interchangeability of said layers, separation of concerns which could make things a lot more easier in different situations. I'm actually am interested in this particular scenario with this particular layering, not really in debating the added value of some layers since this is already the road we've taken and consider it to be good practice. We may reconsider this in the future, I'm not denying.

Comment: @FlorinBombeanu: I absolutely agree that you're trying to be implementation agnostic. But I'm just warning you that saying you're returning an `IQueryable` means that *every* implementation, real or mock, is **guaranteed** to return an object which you can query. If you've done anything involved, you'll know that it's very easy to break the `IQueryable`. It also becomes very difficult to unit test without tightly coupling your tests to your implementations. So yes, I would say there is definitely the potential of a separation of concerns issue.

Comment: *The added value is interchangeability of said layers* In such case nothing related to EF can leak out of your repository - no IQueryable, no lazy-loding etc. If it does, you don't have interchangeable layer because your upper layer is coupled to side effects of your implementation.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka In this case, what should leak out of the repository? After all, IQueryable resides in the System.Linq namespace.

Comment: `IQueryable` is just an interface but the implementation is dependent on Linq provider. When you expose `IQueryable` you believe that you can use everything the `IQueryable` defines but that is not the case when the provider is Linq-to-Entities (Entity Framework) - try to call for example `Last` method on L2E query. `IQueryable` offers more than EF and you must code and test your application with the implementation you are going to use. Replacing with another Linq implementation may or may not work.

Comment: Ok, I understand the different implementations of IQueryable by different providers. But to conclude what do you think it's a better implementation of our situation? To answer your initial question regarding the added value, we need the abstractization of the data layer because we want to make sure we can cover more than one DB engine and we need the abstractization of the repository through services such that we can properly unit test all business scenarios.